setuid not working with C code and system() call
I have NICE-DCV installed in RHEL-8.10 and as root doing a dcv list-sessions  shows all sessions on the system.  But if a user does dcv list-sessions then the output from that is only their session and it doesn't report any other session; this is normal.
In writing C code in an admin effort to pretty the list-session output, and allow all users to see what active sessions there currently are, I attempted to setuid on my /usr/local/bin/dcvlist c executable and it shows as -rwsrwxr-x. 1 root root dcvlist.  As root when I run this dcvlist executable I get expected output of all sessions happening but as a regular user account that still does not happen.
Am I doing something wrong based on what I explained?  Am I mistaken thinking the setuid should also apply to the system("dcv list-sessions") within my C code which it appears not to be?  All my C code is doing is system("dcv list-sessions") ... actually a popen and then I'm just reprinting that output.
also, the dcv program takes many parameters in addition to list-sessions so I don't want to allow sudo access to allow users to run that as root.

This question is similar to: setuid root does not work. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A setuid program changes the effective uid of the process; if an application is checking the real uid (eg via the getuid() call) then it won't see the difference; the real uid is still that of the user.
You can set the real UID inside your program with setuid(0);.  This will work if the effective uid is zero (so from a setuid root program).
You need to be careful with this sort of thing, though; your system("dev ...") call would allow a user to create their own dev command and put it on the PATH first (eg create $HOME/bin/dev and set export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH).  Now they have full root access.
Instead you'd be better off using sudo, properly configured.  This can give fine grained access (eg only allow specific people permission to do this) and provide audit trails, and more.
sudo can be configured to only allow specific options, rather than every option.
eg
%dev ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/dev list-sessions

This will only allow people in the dev group to run sudo dev list-sessions.  If they try to do sudo dev anythingelse then it will not be permitted.

yeah i think the sudo route best solution, thanks

so the sudo works at the prompt and from within the C program, however the NOPASSWD does not work from the system() or popen() call within my C program I get password prompted as my C program runs - type in your correct password then the program continues and I get the correct output

going to ask a separate question regarding NOPASSWD sudo from within a C program system() call.

never mind, the sudoers syntax is exact and strict, it works now with NOPASSWD being effective from within my C code not password prompting
